# How to check if keras tensorflow backend is running on the GPU or CPU?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gpu

I have notebook with GPU:  nvidia-smi

```
Thu Oct 18 20:49:22 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.87                 Driver Version: 390.87                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 540M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     12MiB /   964MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It is running a code Keras:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963084: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 540M major: 2 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.344
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 964.50MiB freeMemory: 917.75MiB
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963633: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1455] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 540M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 2.1) with Cuda compute capability 2.1. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963652: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963663: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-10-18 20:26:08.963673: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
```

Comment: So... give me some more context... when running it says it found a GeForce GPU so it may be ok. Your question is because the first output doesn't show any processes?

Comment: This command might help:
`from keras import backend as K; K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()`
it will list the devices your backend is using (as it is tensorflow).